# Can MySQL set command line aliases? (like git)

Tags: mysql

For example,

I hate always type `git status`, because I do this a lot, I feel waste of time.
so I set a aliases
`git config --global alias.s status`

now I can use `git s` get same result.
I also set:
`git a` for `git add`
`git c` for `git commit`
`git co` for `git checkout`
`git pl` for `git pull`
`git pu` for `git push`

---

Can I do this in MySQL?

I don't want `show databases`
I want `show d`

I don't want`show tables`
I want `show t`